# Matching greedy vs non-greedy operations in Tcl

Tags: regex, tcl

Suppose I want to match a text the following text,

```
[ OK - 977613837 bytes ]
```

I can write-up a regexp in many ways. Consider the following code,

```
set length "\[ OK - 977613837 bytes \]"
puts $length

#can be many ways, I am just keeping 2, to have it for question's sake
puts [ regexp -inline {\[\s+OK\s+-\s+\d+\s+bytes\s+\]} $length ] 
puts [ regexp -inline {\[.*OK.*\d+.*bytes.*\]} $length ]
```

Here both the regexp serve me to get the result to know whether the matched text is available or not.

Lets say I am not bother about the sub-match text and lets assume that the text will be consistent (i.e. it wont have anything after the last right square bracket.). The reason why I am saying the text will be consistent is to avoid the greedy operator to get more text.

I believe both can be of same meaning in this context, with this given conditions.

Might be silly to ask, but which regexp can be of more efficient in terms of execution time ?

Comment: i recommend this `puts [ regexp -inline {\[\s+OK\s+\-\s+\d+\s+bytes\s+\]} $length ] ` because backtracking would be avoided by using this regex.

Comment: Nice question. Tested it out a bit and found some results that surprised me. So far, the fastest is using `{\[\s*OK\s*-\s*\d+\s*bytes\s*\]}`.

Comment: Well, actually, `{\[\s*OK\D*\d+\s*bytes\s*\]}` is the current fastest[.](http://codepad.org/E2gy7Z8w).

Comment: @Jerry: only that last one will match a lot of strings that aren't space-single dash-space.

Comment: `{\[ *OK *- *\d+ +bytes *\]}` is also pretty fast.

Comment: @Hoodiecrow I don't think it matters because the `.` version doesn't attempt to match the dash.

Comment: @Jerry: you are quite right. (To my mind, it does conflict with a bit with the problem description, though.)

Comment: @Dinesh, I actually hid a link in my second comment to your question. Try hovering your mouse over the dot after 'fastest' and you'll get a link where I timed 5 different regex. You could perhaps pick the one you like :)

Comment: Cool, Thanks Jerry :). That helped and I also surprised by the results seen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite hard to predict what the fastest RE will be, especially when there's only a very limited set of inputs. Regular expressions can be fast to match at the beginning but slow generally, or fast to match but slow to fail to match, and so on. You also have to be aware that capturing anything slows the engine down, as does *any* backtracking. Use the `time` command to investigate.

```
% set length "\[ OK - 977613837 bytes \]"
[ OK - 977613837 bytes ]
% puts [regexp -inline {\[\s+OK\s+-\s+\d+\s+bytes\s+\]} $length]
{[ OK - 977613837 bytes ]}
% time {regexp -inline {\[\s+OK\s+-\s+\d+\s+bytes\s+\]} $length}
26 microseconds per iteration
% time {regexp -inline {\[\s+OK\s+-\s+\d+\s+bytes\s+\]} $length} 1000
8.996317 microseconds per iteration
% time {regexp -inline {\[\s+OK\s+-\s+\d+\s+bytes\s+\]} $length} 10000
6.5541893 microseconds per iteration
% time {regexp -inline {\[\s+OK\s+-\s+\d+\s+bytes\s+\]} $length} 100000
6.42272296 microseconds per iteration
```

(Note that increasing the number of iterations makes the time-per-iteration more likely to be accurate.)

Some general points though: Tcl caches the compiled RE so that running the same RE a few times in succession is quick. It's got several ways of managing the cache, but the cache works *very* well with REs in either literals or stored in global/namespace variables (provided you don't modify the variables).

And *make sure* you're using an optimized build of Tcl before running timings. Debugging builds are much slower.

Comment: Thanks Donal for the explanation